# Proving $\sum_{i=1}^n 3^i\log_2(i) \in \theta( 3^n\log_2(n))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity

By definition, we know that:

For  $\sum_{i=1}^n 3^i\log_2(i) $ to be in order of $3^n\log_2(n)$ there needs to exists positive constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that:

- $C_1 |3^n\log_2(n)|  \le  |\sum_{i=1}^n 3^i\log_2(i)|  \le  C_2|3^n\log_2(n)|$

Omega is pretty much given as if we take 1 as a constant we automatically can see the inequality. Proof would be to substract $3^n\log_2(n)$ from both sides and, thus, we would end up with $0 \le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 3^i\log_2(i)$ which is true.

The Big-Oh proof is the tricky one for me. Are we allowed to use a constant that includes $n$ ? It's a question of juggling with the known inequalities and thus isolating out a constant. Not sure which way to look at it.

My question: What value can we use as $C_2$ to validate the Big-Oh definition for the inequality?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: $\theta$ is not a function here.  $f(n) \in \theta(g(n))$ means $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ and $g(n) \in O(f(n))$: equivalently, that there are positive constants $a$ and $b$ such that $a |g(n)| \le |f(n)| \le b |g(n)|$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Hint: $3^n \log_2(n) \le \sum_{i=1}^n 3^i \log_2(i) \le \log_2(n) \sum_{i=1}^n 3^i$.